# Calling/Invoking a void method (Java Homework-Game of Life example)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, matrix, conways-game-of-life

I am having trouble manipulating an array in this Game of Life example code.

Situation:
"Game of life" is a cellular automation invented by John Conway. It consists of a grid of cells which can live/die/multiply based on mathematical rules. The live cells and dead cells in this grid are manipulated with the `next()` method, with nPals being the initial state of the grid.

Question: 
My question - which is rather elementary, I know - is how do I use the `next()` method on `nPals` to give me the next stage?

Attempts:
My attempts so far lie along the lines of the following - both of which seem rather similar looking back.

- `nPals.next();`
- `int newNPALS[][] = nPals.next(); // and then printing the array newNPALS`

Any ideas would be most appreciated!

Code:

```
public class GameOfLife {
static int nPals[][] = {
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,2,3,2,1,0},
    {0,2,102,104,102,2,0},
    {0,3,104,8,104,3,0},
    {0,2,102,104,102,2,0},
    {0,1,2,3,2,1,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    };
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Initial Stage
    System.out.println("   >>First Stage<<");
    printMatrix(nPals);
    //Second Stage
    System.out.println("\n   >>Second Stage<<");
    printMatrix(nPals);
}//end main

static Stack<Integer>stk=new Stack<Integer>();
static final int LIVE=100;
static final int MAXGRIDSIZE=1024;
public static void next(){
    for (int i=0;i<nPals.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<nPals[i].length;j++){
            switch(nPals[i][j]){
            case LIVE+0:case LIVE+1:case LIVE+4:
            case LIVE+5:case LIVE+6:case LIVE+7:
                stk.push(-(i*MAXGRIDSIZE+j));       //death
                nPals[i][j]-=LIVE;
                break;
            case 3:
                stk.push(i*MAXGRIDSIZE+j);          //life
                nPals[i][j]+=LIVE;
                break;
            }//end switch
        }//end for j
    }//end for i
    while(!stk.isEmpty()){
        int k=stk.pop();
        if(k>0)inc(k/MAXGRIDSIZE,k%MAXGRIDSIZE);
        else{
            k=-k;
            dec(k/MAXGRIDSIZE,k%MAXGRIDSIZE);
        }//end if 
    }//end while
}//end next

private static void inc(int i, int j) {

}

private static void dec(int i, int j){
    if(i!=0){
    //3 squares on top
        if(j!=0) minus(i-1,j-1);
        minus(i-1,j);
        if(j!=nPals[i].length-1)minus(i-1,j+1);
    }
    //2 on either side
    if(j!=0)minus(i,j-1);
    if(j!=nPals[i].length-1)minus(i,j+1);
    if(i!=nPals.length-1){
    //3 squares on bottom
        if(j!=0)minus(i+1,j-1);
        minus(i+1,j);
        if(j!=nPals[i].length-1)minus(i+1,j+1);
    }
}

private static void minus(int i, int j){
    if(nPals[i][j]>0)nPals[i][j]--;
}
private static void plus(int i, int j){
    if(nPals[i][j]<=0)nPals[i][j]++;
}

//This is just for explaining printMatrix above, otherwise immaterial
public static <E> void printMatrix(int[][] m){
    for(int[] rows:m){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rows));
    }
}//end printMatrix
}//end GameOfLife
```

Output:

```
   >>First Stage<<
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 102, 104, 102, 2, 0]
[0, 3, 104, 8, 104, 3, 0]
[0, 2, 102, 104, 102, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

   >>Second Stage<< /* currently unchanged */
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 102, 104, 102, 2, 0]
[0, 3, 104, 8, 104, 3, 0]
[0, 2, 102, 104, 102, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: explain the game of life. Don't expect everyone to know how it works

Comment: One common problem with GoL implementations is attempting to both update and use a single array for information on cell survival.  Keep two arrays.  BTW - it really seems you've reproduced your homework with a `/* fill in code here */` instruction.  SO does not work that way.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I don't understand the second half of your comment. I wasn't trying to hide the fact that it's school work. I just didn't want to bombard users with code that might not necessarily be relevant. For future reference, what would be a better way of putting in code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about and http://sscce.org

Comment: *'I just didn't want to bombard users with code that might not necessarily be relevant."*  The code that **is** relevant is what you've tried.  Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a method that does something like:

```
public void doTurn(int [][]m) {

//manipulate matrix

}
```

And call that for each stage.

Answer (score 0):

`nPals` is declared as a `static` array of array of ints (`int[][]`), this means that there is only one `nPals` in your class. The effect is that, within your class, you can always access it. So in your case just `next()` is the correct function call. Just use `nPals` when you need it in that function.

This makes me wonder though why you gave `printMatrix` an `int[][]` parameter..

Anyway, the full code of your main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Initial Stage
    System.out.println("   >>First Stage<<");
    printMatrix(nPals);

    next();

    //Second Stage
    System.out.println("\n   >>Second Stage<<");
    printMatrix(nPals);
}//end main
```